# Android gcm sample gives register: http error 400

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the steps given at http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html and I am getting the below error each time i try to register from my device(running on froyo)

> 07-04 22:48:31.178: D/C2DMRegistrar(3880): [C2DMRegistrar.66] register: http error 400

For **senderId**, I have tried using **projectID**(as per Google), email Id and API key but none worked.

I have android market and signed in google account on the device.

Comment: This is very strange. Although the documentation says that the SENDER_ID is the project id , but it did now work with the project Id but worked with the email ID.

Comment: If register with email address work, that's probably because you have used that email address as the C2DM dev account. The new GCM uses the Project ID (a numeric string) instead. If you're using email address to register, you're still going through C2DM.

Comment: I created another key from the console.And now I am able to register using project_ID also, but now while sending the messages from server , it is giving the [ errorCode=MismatchSenderId ]. Any idea ?

Comment: You cannot send messages to the GCM server using the registration ids from the old C2DM. Basically your server needs to keep track the registration ids, to determine whether they are created from the old C2DM or the new GCM, which your server can then use the correct method to push the notifications.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve all the errors and able to get the notifications. here is a small blogpost and my code for downloading.http://android.amolgupta.in/2012/07/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial.html

Comment: Just try this too. http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 6):

**Response 400 :** Only applies for JSON requests. Indicates that the request could not be parsed as JSON, or it contained invalid fields (for instance, passing a string where a number was expected). The exact failure reason is described in the response and the problem should be addressed before the request can be retried.

You can refer [**`this document`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html) for all available response come from the request.

Comment: Hi Dipali. Thanks for the reply, it was some other error which i was able to fix. Now while sending the messages from server, I am getting the error: [ errorCode=MismatchSenderId ]. Any pointers to help?

Comment: @AmolGupta, You need to set the sender_id in the client code with the email address you registered to the `gcm servers` (the one you use in the http post to send messages)

Comment: well the comments on this question suggest that if i put the emailId, I would actually be going the C2DM way instead of GCM

Comment: Thanks, i was able to fix it. here are the details along with the code  http://android.amolgupta.in/2012/07/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial.html